# How to download all files in a folder from GCS cloud bucket using python client api?

Tags: python, gcloud, google-api-python-client

How to download all files in a folder from GCS cloud bucket using python client api?
Files like .docx and .pdf

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide your attempts and get familiar on the best way to post question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

use a downloaded credentials file to create the client, see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication)
this docs tells you to export the file location, but I personally prefer the method used below as it allows for different credentials within the same application.

IMHO separation of what each serviceaccount can access increases security by tenfold. It's also usefull when dealing with different projects in the same app.

Note that you'll also have to give the serviceaccount the permission [Storage Object Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles), or one with more permissions.
Always use the least needed to due to security considerations

**requirements.txt**

```
google-cloud-storage
```

**main.py**

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from os import makedirs


# use a downloaded credentials file to create the client, see
# https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication
# this docs tells you to export the file location, but I personally 
# prefer the method used below as it allows for different credentials 
# within the same application.
# IMHO separation of what each serviceaccount can access increases
# security by tenfold. It's also usefull when dealing with different
# projects in the same app.
# 
#
# Note that you'll also have to give the serviceaccount the
# permission "Storage Object Viewer", or one with more permissions.
# Always use the least needed to due to security considerations
# https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles


cred_json_file_path = 'path/to/file/credentials.json'
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(cred_json_file_path)


def download_blob(bucket: storage.Bucket, remotefile: str, localpath: str='.'):
    """downloads from remotepath to localpath"""
    localrelativepath = '/'.join(remotefile.split('/')[:-1])
    totalpath = f'{localpath}/{localrelativepath}'
    filename = f'{localpath}/{remotefile}'
    makedirs(totalpath, exist_ok=True)
    print(f'Current file details:\n  remote file: {remotefile}\n  local file:  {filename}\n')
    blob = storage.Blob(remotefile, bucket)
    blob.download_to_filename(filename, client=client)


def download_blob_list(bucketname: str, bloblist: list, localpath: str='.'):
    """downloads a list of blobs to localpath"""
    bucket = storage.Bucket(client, name=bucketname)
    for blob in bloblist:
        download_blob(bucket, blob, localpath)


def list_blobs(bucketname: str, remotepath: str=None, filetypes: list=[]) -> list:
    """returns a list of blobs filtered by remotepath and filetypes
    remotepath and filetypes are optional"""
    result = []
    blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucketname, prefix=remotepath))
    for blob in blobs:
        name = str(blob.name)
        # skip "folder" names
        if not name.endswith('/'):
            # do we need to filter file types?
            if len(filetypes) > 0:
                for filetype in filetypes:
                    if name.endswith(filetype):
                        result.append(name)
            else:
                result.append(name)
    return result


bucketname = 'bucketnamegoeshere'
foldername = 'foldernamegoeshere'
filetypes = ['.pdf', '.docx'] # list of extentions to return
bloblist = list_blobs(bucketname, remotepath=foldername, filetypes=filetypes)

# I'm just using the bucketname for localpath for download location.
# should work with any path
download_blob_list(bucketname, bloblist, localpath=bucketname)
```